# Association :patient not found, rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, associations

I'm trying to associate a relation betwen 1 patient with a consultation, but I'm getting a error:

Association :patient not found

In the model I have:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :consultums, through: :patients
end

class Consultum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patients
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :recetum
end
```

in the controller I have:

```
class ConsultationController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_consultum, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @consultation = Consultum.all
    respond_with(@consultation)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@consultum)
  end

## when I try to create a new consultation, throw me the error ##

  def new
    @consultum = Consultum.new
    # patient_id
    respond_with(@consultum)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @consultum = Consultum.new(consultum_params)
    @consultum.save 
    respond_with(@consultum)
  end

  def update
    @consultum.update(consultum_params)
    respond_with(@consultum)
  end

  def destroy
    @consultum.destroy
    respond_with(@consultum)
  end


  # def patient_id
  #   patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
  #   # patient = @patient.id
  #   @consultum.patient_id = patient
  # end

  private
    def set_consultum
      @consultum = Consultum.find(params[:id])
    end

    def consultum_params
      params.require(:consultum).permit(:Reason_Consultation, :Diagnostic, :TX, :Labs, :Observations, :patient_id)
    end
end
```

so, as you can see I create the function patient_id, and I'm trying to retrieve the id from the 'patient' and put into patient_id in 'consultum' table, but seems not work...

if I uncomment patient_id function throw me this error:

[Couldn't find Patient without an ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxYhH.png)

I'm stuck, any idea?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

in my view I have:

consultation/new.html.erb

```
<div class="page-header">
  <%= link_to consultation_path, class: 'btn btn-default' do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
    Back
  <% end %>
  <h1>New consultum</h1>
</div>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@consultum) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :Reason_Consultation %>
    <%= f.input :Diagnostic %>
    <%= f.input :TX, placeholder: "optional" %>
    <%= f.input :Labs, placeholder: "optional" %>
    <%= f.input :Observations, placeholder: "optional" %>
    <%= f.association :patient %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Save Consultation" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The action 'new' doesn't receive param ID, that's the reason.  You must call the action 'new' passing the paciente 'ID'.

Comment: When calling the new action you also have to send the `paciente` id. But your view is not sending this id. Could you post your view to see what is send.

Comment: Please check your app with spanish and english code. For standar include your code (controller, models, view) in english.

Comment: ok, I edit post to translate spanish to english, sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @Eleazar Enrique, how can I call the action 'new' and pass the patient 'id'to the action? Thanks for your help

Comment: @CarlosGómez no problem. We are to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

When creating associations in rails pay super close attention to the pluralization!

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :consultums, through: :patients
end

class Consultum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patients
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :recetum
end
```

You will notice that your `Consultum` class does not have a `patient` relation. It has `belongs_to :patients`.

```
class Consultum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :recetum
end
```

**Also your attribute naming should follow the Ruby conventions!**

Ruby uses `snake_case` for naming attributes and methods and will automatically treat any identifier which begins with an UPPERCASE letter as a constant!

This is not just a stylistic issue - MRI Ruby will let you reassign constants with a warning. Other versions or future versions may be less lenient.

```
Bad                       Good
.Reason_Consultation      .reason_consultation
.Diagnostic               .diagnostic
.TX                       .tx
.Lab                      .lab
.Observations             .observations
```

https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Comment: Thank you, I followed your comment and I change attributes for rails convention.

Comment: If I understood well in the Consultum class, then I have to remove belongs_to :patient, and change for a relation 1 to many? has_many :patients ??

This is why I can't associate patient and consultation? 

Thank's for your time.

Comment: No, the Consultum should `belong_to :patient`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

**To call an action you can pass parameters as follow:**

```
link_to "New Consultum", new_consultum_path(:id => here, yo have to put the paciente id)
```

**Hope this helps!**